# redirect with parameters based on clicked item

Tags: python, flask, redirect

In the past, I have used flask forms to take a piece of info from a form and redirect to the correct page, based on this form input, e.g.:

```
def index():
    form = utils.IndexForm()
    choices_lst = form.choices_lst

    choice=form.type_of_testing.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("choice: ",form.type_of_testing.data)

        if form.type_of_testing.data in choices_lst:
            print('Going to type1 form')
            return redirect(url_for("type1",choice=choice))
        else:
            print('Going to type2 form')
            return redirect(url_for("type2",choice=choice))

    else:
        print("Validation Failed")
        print(form.errors)
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)
```

I now want to change this logic and remove the form and instead just have 3 buttons to chose from, and go to the correct page based on which button is clicked, and pass along the correct ID associated with the button.

My `route.py` page current likes like this:

```
@app.route('/choices/',methods=['GET'])
def choices():
    choice_list = [1,2,3]

    return render_template('choices.html',choice_lst=choice_lst)


@app.route('/choice_info/')
def event_info():
    #some logic based off of the choice data passed along
    return render_template('choice_info.html')
```

The HTML for the `choices.html` page looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{%block title%}Networking{%endblock%}

{%block main_content%}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
    <table class="table">
    <tbody>
     {% for choice in choice_lst %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/{{ choice['name'] }}"><img src={{ choice["imageURL"] }}> </a></td>

            </tr>

     {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```

I thought that passing the `choice[name]` as a parameter to the URL would work, but I am getting a 404 not found error. I can't quite figure out how to pass the correct choice along in my HHTML, and Im not sure what functions I need in my  `route.py` code to make the logic work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import url_for

@app.route('/choices/',methods=['GET'])
def choices():
    choice_list = [
       {'name': url_for('event_info', choice_id=1)},
       {'name': url_for('event_info', choice_id=2)},
       {'name': url_for('event_info', choice_id=3)}]

return render_template('choices.html',choice_lst=choice_lst)


@app.route('/choice_info/<choice_id>')
def event_info(choice_id: int):
    #some logic based off of the choice data passed along
    return render_template('choice_info.html')
```

Also, remove the `/` from `"/{{ choice['name'] }}"` in this line in your HTML:

```
<a href="/{{ choice['name'] }}"><img src={{ choice["imageURL"] }}> </a>
```

Comment: Im getting the error: `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app.event_info'. Did you mean 'event_info' instead?`

Comment: Fixed the format for `url_for`.